# SwiftUI set navigationViewStyle based on device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to get my navigation view style to be stacked on iPad but default on iPhone.

Code:

```
.navigationViewStyle(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? StackNavigationViewStyle() : DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
```

Giving me the error:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'StackNavigationViewStyle' and 'DefaultNavigationViewStyle'

Are these not both NavigationViewStyle subclasses?

Comment: no, they are structs, and `NavigationViewStyle` is protocol.

Comment: so how do I do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend to extract it into simple wrapper modifier and use it in place where needed. Here is modifier:

### Update:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    public func currentDeviceNavigationViewStyle() -> some View {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            self.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        } else {
            self.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI 1.0 (backward-compatible)

```
extension View {
    public func currentDeviceNavigationViewStyle() -> AnyView {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()))
        } else {
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is vary simple and straight forward, but it will cause loosing the `View` type.

Comment: If it is last in modifiers list that does not matter, but still works. Moreover `.navigationViewStyle` itself returns opaque view, so no difference.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Xcode 12.5. It results in the compile error "Instance method 'navigationViewStyle' requires that 'AnyView' conform to 'NavigationViewStyle'"

Answer (score 3):

Thats because `? :` should always return values with same type.

You can implement a custom conditional modifier extension like this:

```
extension View {
    public func modify<T, U>(if condition: Bool, then modifierT: T, else modifierU: U) -> some View where T: ViewModifier, U: ViewModifier {
        Group {
            if condition {
                modifier(modifierT)
            } else {
                modifier(modifierU)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implement custom modifiers like this:

```
struct IPadNavigationViewStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View { content.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) }
}

struct IPhoneNavigationViewStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View { content.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle()) }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
    .modify(if: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad, then: IPadNavigationViewStyle(), else: IPhoneNavigationViewStyle() )
```

Comment: great solution!