# SwiftUI view crashes when updating NavigationLinks in same NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigation

To explain this behavior, I have built a simplified project that creates same behavior as my working project. Please keep in mind that my real project is much bigger and have more constraints than this one.

I have a simple `struct` with only an `Int` as property (named `MyObject`) and a model that stores 6 `MyObject`.

```swift
struct MyObject: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
}

final class Model: ObservableObject {
    let objects: [MyObject] = [
        MyObject(id: 1),
        MyObject(id: 2),
        MyObject(id: 3),
        MyObject(id: 4),
        MyObject(id: 5),
        MyObject(id: 6)
    ]
}
```

Please note that in my real project, `Model` is more complicated (loading from JSON).

Then I have a `FavoritesManager` that can add and remove a `MyObject` as favorite. It has a `@Published` array of ids (`Int`):

```swift
final class FavoritesManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var favoritesIds = [Int]()
    
    func addToFavorites(object: MyObject) {
        guard !favoritesIds.contains(object.id) else { return }
        favoritesIds.append(object.id)
    }
    
    func removeFromFavorites(object: MyObject) {
        if let index = favoritesIds.firstIndex(of: object.id) {
            favoritesIds.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

My `App` struct creates Model and FavoritesManager and injects them in my first view:

```swift
@main
struct testAppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    @StateObject private var favoritesManager = FavoritesManager()    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(model)
                .environmentObject(favoritesManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have few views that display my objects:

`ContentView` displays a link to `ObjectsListView` using `NavigationLink` and a `FavoritesView`. In my real project, `ObjectsListView` does not display all objects, only a selection (by category for example).

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ObjectsListView(objects: model.objects), label: {
                        Text("List of objects")
                    }
                )
                FavoritesView()
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`FavoritesView` displays ids of current selected favorites. It observes `FavoritesManager` to update its body when a favorite is added/removed.

Important: it creates a new `NavigationLink` to favorites details view. If you remove this link, bug does not happen.

```swift
struct FavoritesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    @EnvironmentObject var favoritesManager: FavoritesManager
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Favorites:")
            let favoriteObjects = model.objects.filter( { favoritesManager.favoritesIds.contains($0.id) })
            ForEach(favoriteObjects) { object in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(object: object), label: {
                    Text("\(object.id)")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ObjectsListView` simply displays objects and makes a link to `DetailsView`.

```swift
struct ObjectsListView: View {
    @State var objects: [MyObject]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(objects) { object in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(object: object), label: { Text("Object \(object.id)")})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`DetailsView` displays object details and add a button to add/remove current object as favorite.
If you press the star, current object will be added as favorite (as expected) and `FavoritesView` will be updated to display/remove this new id (as expected).

But here is the bug: as soon as you press the star, current view (`DetailsView`) disappears and it goes back (without animation) to previous view (`ObjectsListView`).

```swift
struct DetailsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var favoritesManager: FavoritesManager
    @State var object: MyObject
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("You're on object \(object.id) detail page")
                
                Button(action: {
                    if favoritesManager.favoritesIds.contains(object.id) {
                        favoritesManager.removeFromFavorites(object: object)
                    },
                    else {
                        favoritesManager.addToFavorites(object: object)
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: favoritesManager.favoritesIds.contains(object.id) ? "star.fill" : "star")
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                })
            }
            
            Text("Bug is here: if your press the star, it will go back to previous view.")
                .font(.caption)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

You can download [complete example project here](https://apps.gander.family/testapp.zip).

You may ask why I don't display objects list in `ContentView` directly. It is because of my real project. It displays objects classified by categories in lists. I have reproduce this behavior with `ObjectsListView`.

I also need to separated `Model` and `FavoritesManager` because in my real project I don't want that my `ContentView`'s body is updated everytime a favorite is added/removed. That's why I have moved all favorites displaying in `FavoritesView`.

I believe that this issue happens because I add/remove `NavigationLinks` in current `NavigationView`. And it looks like it is reloading whole navigation hierarchy. But I can't figure out how to get expected result (staying in `DetailsView` when pressing star button) with same views hierarchy. I may do something wrong somewhere...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swiftui: problem with adding a property to data struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631716/swiftui-problem-with-adding-a-property-to-data-struct)

Comment: Mmh, I'm really not sure. I don't get which part of my code should be a Binding..? I think my question is about NavigationLink/View.

Comment: It is the Binding, the State variables are sources of truth. You variable is a let too which means it doesn’t change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to your `NavigationView` in `ContentView`.
With that, your code works well for me,  I can press the star in `DetailsView`, and it remains displayed. It does not
go back to the previous View. Using macos 12.2, Xcode 13.2,
targets ios 15.2 and macCatalyst 12.1. Tested on real devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works (in example project and my real one)! But do you understand why this behavior occurs? But setting .stack to NavigationView will change UI on iPad...

Comment: the source code is closed, so I cannot see why this behaviour occurs.
You can use: `.stack`, `.columns`, `.automatic` on the iPad or anywhere available, 
to customise the `navigationViewStyle` to your liking.

Comment: As on iPad it does not crash. I have used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145043/swiftui-set-navigationviewstyle-based-on-device to keep .automatic NavigationViewStyle on iPad. And set to .stack on iPhone as you suggest. (Reverse condition in this currentDeviceNavigationViewStyle func.)

It does not explain why this occurs. But it fix it.